# accessing a function in the Program.cs that initializes my Form1 from my Form1

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a server/client application and in my client app i initialized my connection in the Program.cs file in which i also initialize my Form application . How can i, lets say, click on an button on my form and call a function in my Program.cs file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting stuff in Program.cs is not recommended, you should instead create new files.

If you want to put it in Program.cs you just add a method there, you need to make it `static` since the `Program` class is `static`.

To call it from a button, just double click the button in the designer and an event handler is created.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Program.YourMethod();
}
```

The same principle applies if you put the code in another file. Create a namespace and a class in that file.

If you make the class/method non static (that's how you usually do) you need to instantiate your class too.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var yourObject = new YourClass();
    yourObject.YourMethod();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The Think is i added the server call functions in the program.cs . Should i embed the server code to the form code ?

Comment: @Badescu Alexandru, You should probably create a class called `Server` (in a separate file) and add all your server logic to that class. Then you instantiate the server in the form, something like this: `Server myServer = new Server("hostname");`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the function is public and static, e.g.

```
public static void Foo()
{
    MessageBox.Show("foo");
}
```

Simply have such code in the button click event:

```
Program.Foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make the method static, you can just call it like this:

```
class Program
{
    // ...

    public static void SendMessage(object obj)
    {
        // Send your message.
    }
}
```

Then call the method:

```
Program.SendMessage(whatToSend);
```

Answer (score 0):

to do any inheritance from any class to program.cs, we can not do directly because it will consists only static classes so for that we can get by making access modifier static for example as shown below

```
private static IinterfaceName xxx;
public program(IinterfaceName xx){
xxx=xx;
}
```

so using this kind will be helpful